A rabbi takes a boat ride home
A rabbi travels on boat from his location to his home.
The boat is scheduled to arrive to the destination the day before Shabbat. All passengers who boarded were required to pay an equal amount. The pay included money allocated to: boat amenities, all meals, living quarters, crew labor, and all construction materials needed during the voyage. The destination where the rabbi debarks requires a very tall ladder to get from the boat to the dock. The boat had a sufficient ladder when it departed.
While in route there was a storm. In the storm the boat’s ladder was damaged and as a result it was used as firewood later that day. The storm also caused a time delay and the new arrival day is Shabbat.
After sunrise on Shabbat the boat crew constructed a new ladder using only the materials paid for by the passenger pay.
What methods of disembarking may the Rabbi use?

Where was the boat when Shabbat began? Outside the Techum?

The boat sailed continuously from the day before. The boat sailed through all hours on Shabbat until it arrived at its destination. The crew finished the new ladder a bit after mid-day on Shabbat.

The title sounds like the start of a joke

I fear you've missed the point entirely here. The issue is techum shabbos -- how far you can travel (even by walking with nothing in your pockets) outside of a city.
If at the start of Shabbos the ship was more than a mile from shore, then this Jewish fellow -- man, woman, ordained -- doesn't matter! -- then they're not allowed to disembark upon arrival. Even if the ladder was pre-set and all of that stuff.
If there is absolutely no way to safely remain on the ship, then he should disembark and then remain in the nearest building for the rest of shabbos. Tel Aviv Airport is actually set up for exactly this scenario. (Well, a delayed flight rather than a ship, but the concepts are all the same.)
If somehow the ship was traveling along a heavily-populated coastline and was very close to a city at the time shabbos started (or they arrived before shabbos started but somehow the crew to unload them didn't show up till after shabbos), then he or she may simply disembark using the ladder. The fact that the ladder wasn't available at the start of shabbos is a moot point. It may be muktzeh, but the prohibition of muktzeh is on moving items. And one would hope that the crew has secured this ladder quite well before any passengers climb down.

hmm. not necessarily. If the water was deeper than 10 tefachim AND the ship never came to a complete rest from the moment Shabbat began until it was within the techum, then the passengers never "acquired" shevitat techum until they were at port. See SA OC 404:1.

If he's the only one departing that day, then plausibly the construction of the ladder was just for him and he can't use it that day.

@DoubleAA all excellent points, but this whole questions seems like a massive case of XY Answer or something. Worldbuilding, perhaps?

Are we not to explore all areas of the law?
